# Is it possibe to extract coordinates for shapes drawn in any graphics manipulation software?

Tags: shapes, drawing

Is there a way of extracting coordinates of shaped which are drawn in a given graphics manipulations software?

Here I give a very basic example.

Image I draw a rectangle in a Paint (it can be any other software), the coordinates of this rectangle are: 520,500 (top left corner), 520,490 (bottom left corner), 1010,500 (top right corner), 1010,  490 (bottom right corner).

Since I draw this shape via a gui + mouse, I can't get the coordinates directly. I have to check each one of them.

Are you aware of any tool, or any method which would allow me to "extract" these coordinates for a shape which is drawn via the GUI?

Comment: Sure. Photoshop, illustrator, Gimp and even word could do this

Comment: "Given", or "any" software? Raster or vector? In-application, or parsed from a file? And how exactly is this relevant to [Graphicdesign.se]?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting to SVG will give you all the data in a text file, making automated or semi-automated extraction fairly easy.

Here's an example using Adobe Illustrator.

[image: SVG in Adobe Illustrator]